# AttributeError: 'Ship' object has no attribute 'bullet_width'

Tags: python, pygame

I am a learner of the Python Crash Course and now I am working on the alien invasion program. I just finished the chapter about adding bullets to my spaceship and when I press the space button, python threw "AttributeError: 'Ship' object has no attribute 'bullet_width'". I had tried to debug it and run it step by step but I couldn't find the mistake I've made. Can anybody help me to deal with it? Here are my codes:
alien_invasion(main code):

```
import sys

import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    # 初始化游戏并创建一个屏幕对象
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    # 创建一艘飞船
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
    # 创建一个用于存储子弹的编组
    bullets = Group()

    bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    # 开始游戏的主循环
    while True:
        gf.check_events(ship, ai_settings, ship, bullets)
        ship.update()
        bullets.update()
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)

run_game()
```

bullet.py:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Bullet(Sprite):
    """一个对飞船发射的子弹进行管理的类"""

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, ship):
        """在飞船所处的位置创建一个子弹对象"""
        super(Bullet, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen

        # 在(0, 0)处创建一个表示子弹的矩形，再设置正确的位置
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, ai_settings.bullet_width,
            ai_settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
        self.rect.top = ship.rect.top

        #存储用小数表示的子弹位置
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

        self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
        self.speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor

    def update(self):
        """向上移动子弹"""
        # 更新表示子弹位置的小数值
        self.y -= self.speed_factor
        # 更新表示子弹的rect的位置
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def draw_bullet(self):
        """在屏幕上绘制子弹"""
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

game_function.py:

```
import sys

import pygame

from bullet import Bullet

def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """响应按键"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        #创建一颗子弹，并将其加入到编组bullet中
        new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
        bullets.add(new_bullet)

def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    """响应松开"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False

def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """响应按键和鼠标事件"""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ship)

def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """更新屏幕上的图像，并切换到新屏幕"""
    # 每次循环时都重绘屏幕
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    # 在飞船和外星人后面重绘所有子弹
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    ship.blitme()

    #让最近绘制的屏幕可见
    pygame.display.flip()
```

ship.py:

```
import pygame

class Ship():
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        """初始化飞船并设置其初始位置"""
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings

        # 加载飞船图像并获取其外接矩形
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        # 将每艘新飞船放在屏幕底部中央
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

        # 在飞船的属性center中存储最小数值
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)

        #移动标志
        self.moving_right = False  
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving_down = False

    def update(self):
        """根据移动标志调整飞船的位置"""
        # 更新飞船的center值，而不是rect
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

        #根据self.center更新rect对象
        self.rect.centerx = self.center

    def blitme(self):
        """在指定位置绘制飞船"""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

settings.py:

```
class Settings():
"""存储《外星人入侵》的所有设置的类"""

def __init__(self):
    """初始化游戏的设置"""
    #屏幕设置
    self.screen_width = 1300
    self.screen_height = 680
    self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    #飞船的设置
    self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5

    #子弹设置
    self.bullet_speed_factor = 1.5
    self.bullet_width = 3
    self.bullet_height = 15
    self.bullet_color = 60, 60, 60
```

Thanks a lot, man!

Answer (score 2):

See the signature of the `check_events` function:

> ```py
> def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
> ```

However, when you call `check_events`, the `ship` is passed twice, but the `screen` is missing:

<s>`gf.check_events(ship, ai_settings, ship, bullets)`</s>

```py
gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had fixed the problem!